# changing of color of "a" tag which is inside "li" tag on "li" hover event in css

Tags: css

I have menu bar constructed from "li" and "a" inside.
In css I'm trying to make some color changes when I move mouse over "li" tag.
if I wright some different background it changes it. but I also want to change the text color of a tag at the same time. 
I write color: something.... but because of "a" tag is not at the border of "li" tag but a bit inside, u need to move mouse little bit inside the button to change the color of "a" tag.

So when "li" hover event is triggered how can I change "a" color also ? Only using css and nothing else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply:

```
li:hover a {
    color: black;
}
```

[Of course that does not work in IE6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t16).

Comment: I'm sick of this old browser support. I'll write some javascript probably and force users to upgrade their browsers. That does it. Oh, and thanks for the help Felix

Answer (score 2):

One thing you might note is that even though the text color will change on rollover, if the **a** element is smaller than the **li** element then the link won't work on the edge of the button/menu. To compensate add padding and     display:block on the **a** tag.