# why doesn't block <a> within <li> accept color set in css file?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand how to change color of "a" tags within "li" elements. I have the following unordered list:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  ...
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  ...
</nav>
```

Why does the following work:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
  color: #333333;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #EC5216;
}
```

But not:

```
li a {
  color: #333333;
}

li:hover a {
  color: #EC5216;
}
```

nor:

```
a {
  color: #333333;
}

a:hover {
  color: #EC5216;
}
```

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784627/changing-of-color-of-a-tag-which-is-inside-li-tag-on-li-hover-event-in-css), but it is still unclear. Thanks ahead of time for the answers!

Comment: Probably another CSS is overriding your style. Try adding `!important`

Comment: He should avoid using !important.

Comment: I agree with @phamous, a higher specificity would be preferred.

Comment: I also agree with @phamous my suggestion was just to demonstrate how to set the selector in a higher priority. Using `!important` should only be used as a last resort

Comment: Thanks! So when I remove the Bootstrap css file, it works with: `a { color: red }`. But with the Bootstrap css file, it doesn't. I guess there is something overriding the style.

Comment: @genomics-geek Basically, as long as the selector path is more targeted to the element, it will get a higher priority. Probably `.navbar-default > .navbar-nav > li > a { color: #333333; }` will also override Bootstrap's css style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
 color: #333333;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {
color: #EC5216;
}
```

has more weight and is more specific than

```
li a {
color: #333333;
}

li:hover a {
color: #EC5216;
}
a {
color: #333333;
}

a:hover {
color: #EC5216;
}
```

Please read more on CSS specificity..
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Thanks this helps. I am still grasping the concept of CSS specificity, I appreciate the tip. I found [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) which is also quite helpful understanding the concept.

Answer (score 3):

There is a hierarchy on the selectors that is counted. The more selectors you put, the higher it's defined style gets in the hierarchy.

Let's say for example you use just

```
a {
 style....
}
```

this a has a total weight of 5.

But if you do a

```
.class a {
 style...
}
```

`.class` has another 5 so 5+5 = 10 and will have higher priority.

You can test this by putting `!important` to lower-hierarchy statements.

see here
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: I came across the same article you mention here - it is really helpful. Thanks!